# Maximo Anywhere online-offline login issue

Tags: maximo-anywhere

I am using Maximo Anywhere 7.5.2.0 - Work Execution App

The issue is , the online - offline login sometime getting failed. The first time of app flashed in the Ipad, I can able to login in the app for the both mode online and offline. After some time I cannot able to login. I got the **"The user name and password combination that you entered is not valid" error** even it is correct credentials.

I have enclosed the logs here.

```
   Object {errorMsg: "The user name and password combination that you entered is not valid."} "
    ----------------------------------------
    rejected at Object.<anonymous> (http://11.11.11.11:0989/MaximoAnywhere/apps/services/preview/WorkExecution/common/0/default/js/platform/auth/UserAuthenticationManager.js:498:17)
    at http://11.11.11.11:0989/MaximoAnywhere/apps/services/preview/WorkExecution/common/0/default/dojo/dojo.js:2:285161
    at _7c0 (http://11.11.11.11:0989/MaximoAnywhere/apps/services/preview/WorkExecution/common/0/default/dojo/dojo.js:2:273376)
    at _7ba (http://11.11.11.11:0989/MaximoAnywhere/apps/services/preview/WorkExecution/common/0/default/dojo/dojo.js:2:273240)
    at _7d8.reject (http://11.11.11.11:0989/MaximoAnywhere/apps/services/preview/WorkExecution/common/0/default/dojo/dojo.js:2:274951)
    at _7c6 (http://11.11.11.11:0989/MaximoAnywhere/apps/services/preview/WorkExecution/common/0/default/dojo/dojo.js:2:274017)
    at _7c0 (http://11.11.11.11:0989/MaximoAnywhere/apps/services/preview/WorkExecution/common/0/default/dojo/dojo.js:2:273657)
    at _7ba (http://11.11.11.11:0989/MaximoAnywhere/apps/services/preview/WorkExecution/common/0/default/dojo/dojo.js:2:273240)
    at _7d8.reject (http://11.11.11.11:0989/MaximoAnywhere/apps/services/preview/WorkExecution/common/0/default/dojo/dojo.js:2:274951)
    at AbstractChallengeHandler.<anonymous> (http://11.11.11.11:0989/MaximoAnywhere/apps/services/preview/WorkExecution/common/0/default/js/platform/auth/CustomChallengeHandler.js:98:18)
    ----------------------------------------
Error
    at Promise.then._7cd.then (http://11.11.11.11:0989/MaximoAnywhere/apps/services/preview/WorkExecution/common/0/default/dojo/dojo.js:2:275189)
    at declare.loginClickHandler (http://11.11.11.11:0989/MaximoAnywhere/apps/services/preview/WorkExecution/common/0/default/js/platform/handlers/LoginHandler.js:78:4)
    at null.<anonymous> (http://11.11.11.11:0989/MaximoAnywhere/apps/services/preview/WorkExecution/common/0/default/js/platform/ui/control/UserInterface.js:850:47)
    at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (http://11.11.11.11:0989/MaximoAnywhere/apps/services/preview/WorkExecution/common/0/default/dojo/dojo.js:2:285161)
    at Function.on.emit (http://11.11.11.11:0989/MaximoAnywhere/apps/services/preview/WorkExecution/common/0/default/dojo/dojo.js:2:557950)
    at null.<anonymous> (http://11.11.11.11:0989/MaximoAnywhere/apps/services/preview/WorkExecution/common/0/default/js/platform/ui/control/UserInterface.js:139:12)
    at HTMLFormElement.<anonymous> (http://11.11.11.11:0989/MaximoAnywhere/apps/services/preview/WorkExecution/common/0/default/dojo/dojo.js:2:285161)"_1047 @ dojo.js:2(anonymous function) @ dojo.js:2_142.filter @ dojo.js:2_1055 @ dojo.js:2
dojo.js:2 Object {responseJSON: Object, status: 401} "
    ----------------------------------------
    rejected at AbstractChallengeHandler.<anonymous> (http://11.11.11.11:0989/MaximoAnywhere/apps/services/preview/WorkExecution/common/0/default/js/platform/auth/CustomChallengeHandler.js:98:18)
    at http://11.11.11.11:0989/MaximoAnywhere/apps/services/preview/WorkExecution/common/0/default/dojo/dojo.js:2:285161
    at onLoginFormResponse (http://11.11.11.11:0989/MaximoAnywhere/apps/services/preview/WorkExecution/common/0/default/worklight/worklight.js:9549:5)
    at klass.window.WLJSX.Ajax.Request.WLJSX.Class.create.respondToReadyState (http://11.11.11.11:0989/MaximoAnywhere/apps/services/preview/WorkExecution/common/0/default/worklight/worklight.js:1184:28)
    at klass.window.WLJSX.Ajax.Request.WLJSX.Class.create.onStateChange (http://11.11.11.11:0989/MaximoAnywhere/apps/services/preview/WorkExecution/common/0/default/worklight/worklight.js:1117:9)
    at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (http://11.11.11.11:0989/MaximoAnywhere/apps/services/preview/WorkExecution/common/0/default/worklight/worklight.js:958:20)
    ----------------------------------------
Error
    at Promise.then._7cd.then (http://11.11.11.11:0989/MaximoAnywhere/apps/services/preview/WorkExecution/common/0/default/dojo/dojo.js:2:275189)
    at Object.<anonymous> (http://11.11.11.11:0989/MaximoAnywhere/apps/services/preview/WorkExecution/common/0/default/js/platform/auth/UserAuthenticationManager.js:400:52)
    at http://11.11.11.11:0989/MaximoAnywhere/apps/services/preview/WorkExecution/common/0/default/dojo/dojo.js:2:285161
    at _7c0 (http://11.11.11.11:0989/MaximoAnywhere/apps/services/preview/WorkExecution/common/0/default/dojo/dojo.js:2:273376)
    at Promise.then._7cd.then (http://11.11.11.11:0989/MaximoAnywhere/apps/services/preview/WorkExecution/common/0/default/dojo/dojo.js:2:275270)
    at Object.lang.mixin._realmAuthentication (http://11.11.11.11:0989/MaximoAnywhere/apps/services/preview/WorkExecution/common/0/default/js/platform/auth/UserAuthenticationManager.js:398:4)
    at Object.<anonymous> (http://11.11.11.11:0989/MaximoAnywhere/apps/services/preview/WorkExecution/common/0/default/js/platform/auth/UserAuthenticationManager.js:343:10)
    at http://11.11.11.11:0989/MaximoAnywhere/apps/services/preview/WorkExecution/common/0/default/dojo/dojo.js:2:285161
    at _7c0 (http://11.11.11.11:0989/MaximoAnywhere/apps/services/preview/WorkExecution/common/0/default/dojo/dojo.js:2:273376)
    at Promise.then._7cd.then (http://11.11.11.11:0989/MaximoAnywhere/apps/services/preview/WorkExecution/common/0/default/dojo/dojo.js:2:275270)

Even the different user with correct credentials not able to login. It is start working only I restarted the server. I faced this issue very often.  Kindly advice.
```

Any help would be appreciated. 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Offline login requires that you have logged in previously as this user before.  It stores this information in the localStorage of the application.  If offline login seems to be breaking on iOS, this might be a known issue that we've found and fixed as an iFix.

The first time you login, you must have a server connection to download the data initially and validate your username/password.

Are you using an embedded worklight or standalone worklight server?  You should check the server logs to see if the server is actually running while you're trying to login as the second user.

UPDATE: 
The only thing I can think of here, is that your worklight server is failing to respond to the initial WL.Client.connect somehow.  Either it's too slow, or maybe running out of heap space.  So when it's time to actually try and WL.login with our challenge handler, that handshaking has failed..

1. Check the heapsize of your worklight server make sure it's large enough
2. Check the connect timeout in our Startup.js file being used with the WL.Client.connect method, and bump it way up to be larger and see if it fixes the problem.

Comment: I am using standalone worklight server . I got the following error while login,  Error : WLTC0017E: Resources rolled back due to setRollbackOnly() being called.
[3/14/16 15:00:32:235 MYT] 0000029f webapp        E com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp logServletError SRVE0293E: [Servlet Error]-[GadgetAPIServlet]: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.worklight.gadgets.GadgetRuntimeException: Invalid gadget request format: /WorkExecution/iphone/my_custom_auth_request_url. Unknown handler path: my_custom_auth_request_url

Comment: Unknown handler path usually means that the original handshaking between the device and the worklight server failed, if you go to the Worklight Console simulator http://yourhost:9080/worklightconsole, and try to login there, does it work?  Is the iphone version of your application deployed to the standalone worklight server?

Comment: Yes. It is working in Worklight console simulator.But sometimes I am facing the same issue in simulator also. Yes. I have deployed the Iphone version 9.2 in the standalone worklight server

Comment: The only thing I can think of here, is that your worklight server is extremely slow and the initial WL.client.connect is failing, so when it's time to actually try and WL.login with our challenge handler, that handshaking has failed.